# RegEx and AJAX having trouble with double quotes

Tags: php, regex, jquery

I'm having some trouble with this:

Javascript

```
 var data = $.param ( { caption: captionBox.val() } );
 //then I send the str via ajax
```

PHP

```
 urldecode ( $_POST ( 'caption' ) );
 preg_match("!caption=(?<caption>[a-zA-Z0-9\!\#\@%\$\(\)\[\]\+\?\.\^\\\;\:\<\> \&']+)!", $caption, $matches);
```

Works fine for normal strings and strings with most special characters, however, double quotes  never work. I'm pretty sure that it's a problem with the reg ex, but I've tried ", \", \\" - many variations, and still no good.

Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, added \" to my reg ex, and now it's accepting one of the quotes, but only after the first character. Then I discovered that it doesn't accept any special characters that are the first character in a caption. 

I suck at reg ex.

Comment: Maybe if you explained what the reg ex is supposed to do? Give some examples of possible input strings and which part(s) you want matched.

Comment: It's adding a caption to an image, so really I want to accept any character.

Comment: The problem I'm running into is this string: 'ok' doesn't work but this string: o'k' does.

Comment: If you want to accept _any_ character why are you specifying a long list of specific characters? Change `[yourlonglist]+` to `.+`, because in a regex `.` matches any character. Is the purpose here to extract whatever comes after the initial "=" sign?

Comment: Yes after the initial =, but sadly the dot did not work

Answer (score 0):

Even though the POST body, when sending the data in JavaScript, looks like "caption=...", you do not have to parse that by hand. PHP does the job for you:

```
$captionBox = urldecode($_POST['caption']);
```

`$captionBox` now contains your string, as provided by `captionBox.val()` in the javascript.

Comment: Actually, this is just part of the string that I'm parsing. I simplified it to the part with the problem. I'm actually matching 6 other patterns at the same time.